# Get image file size if it is not direct link

Tags: php

I have the following code in my image.php file

```
<?php 

if ($_GET['id'] == 1)
echo '<img src="Koala.jpg">';

?>
```

How can I get image size in kilobytes if I only know URL: `http://localhost/test/image.php?id=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) to get the image's file size.

> Returns the size of the file in bytes, or FALSE (and generates an error of level E_WARNING) in case of an error.

```
$filename = "Koala.jpg";

$size = filesize($filename) . ' B';

$size = number_format($size / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
```

This will return the file size of the image in kilobytes.

---

If you only know the URL, you can use [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php):

```
function remote_file_size($url){
    $data = get_headers($url, true);
    if (isset($data['Content-Length']))
    return (int) $data['Content-Length'];
}

echo remote_file_size('http://example.com/image.png');
```

Method referenced from http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/get-remote-file-size-using-php.html.

Comment: But I only know the URL